# Python pandas: Mean on dataframe with uint16 gives wrong result

Tags: python, pandas, mean, unsigned-integer

Using the mean method on a dataframe with a uint16 column gives the wrong answer. When I add a  duplicate column with the int16 dtype then both columns give the correct mean. What's going on? I added an issue at github. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7976

```
 Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jun  2 2014, 12:48:16)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: import random

In [4]:

In [4]: np.__version__
Out[4]: '1.8.1'

In [5]: pd.__version__
Out[5]: '0.14.0'

In [6]:

In [6]: y = np.array([random.randint(1900,2000) for x in range(0,2000)])

In [7]: y.mean()
Out[7]: 1950.0115000000001

In [8]: y.astype(np.uint16).mean()
Out[8]: 1950.0115000000001

In [9]:

In [9]: d1 = pd.DataFrame()

In [10]: d1['y'] = y.astype(np.uint16)

In [11]: d1.mean()
Out[11]:
y    16.6995
dtype: float64

In [12]:

In [12]: d1['x'] = y.astype(np.int16)

In [13]: d1.mean()
Out[13]:
y    1950.0115
x    1950.0115
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I can't replicate your results, using numpy 1.8.2 and pandas 0.14.1. When I run `d1.mean()` the first time, it gives me the same result as `y.mean()` and `y.astype(np.uint16).mean()`. Try upgrading and see if that works.

Comment: I am not replicating this with numpy 1.8.1 and pandas 0.13.1.

Comment: this was fixed in 0.14.1: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7976; essentially the default numpy accumulator is not big enough ; numpy calls this a user issue - so pandas now uses the largest dtype available for accumulations